# ¿Cómo paginar más de 8000000 de registros de una tabla en CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, paginación

He empleado códigos de ejemplo de paginacion con la funcionalidad de codeigniter para éste. Con tablas de pocos registros funciona bien.
Pero debo paginar registros de una tabla con mas de 8.000.000 de filas. Y es en ese momento que me quedo como 15 segundos esperando respuesta del servidor con los resultados, o sino se da un error de timeout.
Quise utilizar la paginacion de una forma mas rapida y sencilla, pero por lo que veo con varios registros no es tan eficiente. Existe alguna otra forma?

Este metodo esta en un controlador ...

```
public function paginar(){


    $start_index = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $limit_per_page = 20;


    $total_records= $this->Persona_model->total_registros();
      echo $total_records;
    if( $total_records > 0){

    $params['lista']= $this->Persona_model->obt_lista( $limit_per_page, $start_index);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/Persona/paginar';
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_records;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    // construir  links de paginacion
    $params["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //cargar vista
    $this->load->view("Persona/index",$params);
    }else{
        echo "nada que mostrar";
    }
 }
```

He descubierto que la espera se da mas bien por la llamada a este metodo del modelo, el que obtiene el total de registros.:

```
public function  total_registros(){
 $valor= $this->db->count_all( $this->tabla ); return $valor;
 }
```

Comment: la paginación es una ayuda para el view, depende como tengas armado tu controller y model puede que no le estas pasando el limite y offset a la query, si es eso te carga todo junto y tarda. es eso o necesitas meter mas indices en la tabla para acelerar la consulta. sin código es difícil saber cual de las dos

Comment: si pones la estructura de la tabla `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombredelatabla` armamos un count optimizado, básicamente es: hacer un `select count` de la primary key, definir una key extra, o cambiar el engine

Comment: Como recomendación, si tienes un listado tan grande de datos, te recomiendo que hagas una función que te regrese dichos datos en JSON, y en la vista por medio de Javascript  con JQuery puedes llenar tu tabla, que este caso para el paginado te recomiendo usar un Datatable que te sera mas sencillo manejar toda la información.

Answer (score 2):

yo haria el conteo de registros directamente en la vista de la siguiente forma.
Quiero suponer que estas utilizando `foreach` para mostrar información en la tabla si es así puedes simplemente declarar una variable count que cada que pase haga el sum que haces en la bdd.

```
     <?php 
    $count = 0; //Declaramos la variable que hace el conteo
    foreach($params as $params): 
    ?>

             fila de tabla ...


   <?php 
         $count++; //Aumentamos uno
        endforeach; 
   ?>
```

Con esto evitamos que el conteo lo haga nuestra bdd y lo hacemos directamente en la vista al ir llenando la tabla con la informacion.

ese count puedes simplemente mostrarlo donde se debe: `<?php echo $count;?>`